# Remove all extensions with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to remove extensions from all requests that have an extension and where a file or directory with that name doesn't exist using mod_rewrite. I have it working for one extension, but I want it to be able to work no matter what the extension is. I'm pretty sure that it can be done with a regular extension, but I am not familiar enough with those to know what to do. Here is my code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a couple days of troubleshooting, I have come up with a solution. If it has an extension and a file or a directory doesn't exist, it will remove the extension using a simple match of what is in front of the period. I will also check for trailing slashes and remove them as well. Finally, I will rewrite to the actual page in my sub-directory. I had to put a L on every RewriteRule because it wouldn't work if I didn't.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*\..*$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\..*$ $1 [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1 [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1.html [L]
</IfModule>
```